# Guess the terms in the sequence?

Tags: sequences-and-series, pattern-recognition, gre-exam

I am writing GRE in 2 two months, and I just can't solve these sequence question. Can anyone tell what the missing terms are and what is the pattern here?

> Find the next 4 terms in this sneaky sequence:
>   1, 5, 4, 3, 7, 1, 10, -1, 13, -3, X1,X2,X3

I am supposed to guess the next three terms in the sequence (X1,X2,X3).

Comment: 42, 42, 42 (or 42, 42, 42, 42 if one wants 4 next terms).

Comment: @Did I did not get the joke.

Comment: @Joe: See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/42_%28number%29#The_Hitchhiker.27s_Guide_to_the_Galaxy).

Comment: Any other Pomona alumni (or any Pomona alumnae) who want to join me in holding out for $47,47,47$ instead of Did’s $42,42,42$?

Comment: @BrianM.Scott yup this is what I suspected first :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try looking at the sequence this way:

```
1     4     7    10    13
   5     3     1    -1    -3
```

The top part of the sequence increases by 3 each time and the bottom part of the sequence decreases by 2 each time. The next 3 terms are therefore **16**, **-5** and **19**.

Answer (score 4):

If there are no further restrictions on the sequence, *any* choice of $X_1,X_2,X_3$ is equally valid. It is always possible to construct a polynomial of degree $n$ that passes through $n+1$ datapoints.

Comment: +1 I know. Why do they always ask these dumb questions on the GRE (or any standardized test). Is this something recent? Because a few years ago when I took the GRE (both general and math subject) I don't remember stupid questions like this.